# How to declare a global variable inside an Rscript and call it from Java

Tags: java, r, rserve

I have an Rscript myrscript.R , which is having below code.

```
if(exists("e")==FALSE)
{
  e = new.env()
}

myfun1<-function(file_path)
{
  mydata<-read.csv(file_path)

  e$mydata1 =mydata

  return("firstfunction")
}

myfun2<-function()
{
  e$mydata1  
  names_mydata<-colnames(e$mydata1)  
  nm<-names_mydata[1]

  return(nm)
}
```

I am calling this script from java using the following code.

```
public class mymainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RserveException,  REXPMismatchException {
        String file_path1="/home/jayshree/test_data.csv";
        mymainclass mm=new mymainclass();
        String s = mm.myfun_2(file_path1);
        String l3 = mm.myfun_3();

        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(l3);
    }

    public static String myfun_2(String file_path) throws RserveException, REXPMismatchException
    { 
        RConnection c = new RConnection();
        c.eval("source(\"/home/jayshree/myrscript.R\")");
        c.assign("file_path",file_path);
        String a  = c.eval("myfun1(file_path)").asString();
        return(a);
    }

    public static String myfun_3() throws RserveException, REXPMismatchException
    { 
        RConnection c = new RConnection();
        c.eval("source(\"/home/jayshree/myrscript.R\")");
        String b = c.eval("myfun2()").asString;

        return(b);
    }
}
```

While running this from java. It throwing mismatch error. The error is coming because, while calling the second function of the R script.The value of global variable e$mydata1 is not getting initialized, and is null. But it should not. I ran the code of the script file in R console. It is running fine . But while calling from java, why the global variable thing is not working. Is there any alternative solution.

Comment: `myfun2` takes in argument `file-path` which is not a valid R variable name.

Comment: sorry it was typing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new connection each time, so the calls are entirely independent. I.e, in `myfun_3` you start an empty, new R session so it is expected that it won't have any data loaded. If you want the functions to work on the same session, you have to use the same `RConnection` object.

Comment: Actually the above code is just to try to set a global variable in the Rserve env. I am building an application where I have read the csv file and to perform some analysis and to return the result. Since I was unable to set the global variable each time I need to fetch the data from csv. The data file size is around one gb.

Comment: Now I am able to set a global variable in the Rserve environment but I am getting error "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" My code is working for small csv files but not for big files. I am using os-centos6.5,netbeans8.1,java1.7,R3.2 and glassfish-4.1.1. I have searched in google to solve this I tried each sollution but still getting the same error.

Comment: I did like this and it is working for small data set but not for big data. This a sample example.                                                                                          RConnection c = new RConnection();
     
  c.eval("source(\"/home/jayshree/Desktop/return_data2.R\")");
     RList a  = c.eval("x<<-return_dataframe_2()").asList() ;
      
   c.eval("source(\"/home/jayshree/Desktop/return_data2.R\")");

     
   String[] b = c.eval("return_column_names(x)").asStrings();

Comment: @ Simon , Your Idea worked now I am not using several Rconnection. I am using only one Rconnection. I was fool. I was stuck on this silly mistake.. Thank you Simon